# Install Lubuntu as 2nd OS on encrypted computer?

Tags: debian, lvm, encryption, lubuntu

I have debian installed on my computer which is installed in a full encrypted disk.  Having tried lubuntu in virtual box form and liking it, I want to try lubuntu out on the actual computer instead of virtualbox form.

Concedering my computer is fully encrypted, can I still install lubuntu via the graphical installer without ruining my current debian installation, or will i have to manually partition everything?

Comment: What do you mean by "my computer is fully encrypted"? Do you mean that you used LUKS to encrypt every partition you made on the hard drive, and those partitions take up the full space of the disk?

Answer (score 0):

You could just install the LXDE packages to your current Debian install and use LXDE now. There's a metapackage called `lxde`, if you're using wheezy here's it's "info" page https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/lxde (there are versions for oldstable, stable, sid...) here's a clip:

> ## Package: lxde (4+nmu1)
>
> ### LXDE metapackage
>
> LXDE (the Lightweight X11 Desktop Environment) is a project aimed to provide a desktop environment which is lightweight and fast.
>
> This package is a metapackage depends on the core components and recommended components of the LXDE. It includes lxde-core, lxappearance, lxinput, lxsession-edit, lxshortcut, gpicview, lxterminal, lxmusic, leafpad and xarchiver.
>
> If you just want to pick and choose the core components then feel free to remove this package.

It wouldn't have the Ubuntu-customized packages, but if you really wanted to you could create new partition(s) (shrink existing partitions if needed), and install Lubuntu to the new empty partitions. Personally, I'd just install & use LXDE on your current Debian now, `apt-get install lxde` is a lot easier.